# How to use trap with child tmux process?

Tags: bash, process, tmux, trap

I am looking to execute a function when a child tmux process is terminated.

Consider the following script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function foo
{
  echo "foo exit"
}

trap foo SIGHUP

tmux
```

this script starts tmux. Then, from inside of the tmux session, I run:

```bash
$ tmux kill-session
```

tmux then closes, and I see:

```
[exited]
```

The `foo` function isn't invoked, and I guess its because the parent process doesn't receive SIGHUP.

I am looking to execute the `foo` function when `tmux` is closed. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the signal with `SIGCHLD`.

```
trap foo SIGCHLD
```

That signal gets sent to the parent if a forked child process stopped/terminated. While `SIGHUP` only affects the current process/script as you mentioned.